# Login to sites not working

Tags: blocked-services, login

Since using Tor I cannot login to certain site: e.g., a bitcoin wallet. How can I facilitate this please.

Comment: The Tor project publishes an up-to-the-minute list of Tor relays. One result of this is that any website can check whether your IP number matches that of a tor exit-node and block it if it does. Sometimes the checking (rather than the list) is a bit out dated because the checking website does off-line checking rather than real-time checking. In that case, you might be lucky and use an exit node that is not on the blocked list of the website that you're trying to reach.

Comment: I removed the bit about speed because: 1 that's a separate question & 2 Tor is naturally slower than the "open" internet by nature.

Comment: @user02814 why tor publishes this list? it makes simple to block tor users

Comment: @Fyodor Glebov There has to be an authoritative list of all relays, including exit nodes. Without it, your Tor client would have no way of knowing what relays were available and what services (e.g., Guard, Exit node, middle relay) each relay provided. Without that information, it would be impossible for a Tor client to construct a Tor circuit.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a website and on blocking mechanism used. If it's a by-ip basis block - then all the exit nodes can be disallowed to login and you have no luck. In this case a VPN will help you. If it's not this case - try switching an Exit and you will be lucky one day